# Session variable in Kohana 3 keeps being reset after having been deleted

Tags: php, session, kohana-3

I have a **Notices** class which is used to provide one-time message notifications. The notifications are stored in a Kohana session (cookie) and my getter looks like this (echos are there for debugging purposes):

```
private static function _get($key)
{
    $session = Session::instance();
    $value = $session->get($key);

    echo $key . ': ' . $session->get($key) . '<br />';

    $session->delete($key);

    echo 'deleted ' .$key. ', value now: ' .$session->get($key). '<br /><br />';

    return $value;
}
```

Now, one page I use this class on is the login page. When a user enters incorrect login info it does what I expect it too: displays an error saying "username/password incorrect". This message should then be **deleted** as I've called the getter and the getter deletes it from the session.

However, this is not the case. The message is shown on the next page too. And if I go to any other page which displays notifications, the error is shown there too, until a different error is displayed (say if I enter information on another form incorrectly).

This is what is displayed from the echo's on the page:

> error: Username/password combination is incorrect.
>   deleted error, value now:

Which suggests that the value **is** being deleted, but it's still showing the same thing when I refresh the page.

If it helps this is what the process of setting an error message is like, from a controller I call `Notices::error('message');` which calls this method:

```
public static function error($value = NULL)
{
    return Notices::_notice('error', $value);
}
```

which calls:

```
private static function _notice($key, $value)
{
    // If value is not NULL, then store the notice
    if ( ! is_null($value))
    {
        Notices::_set($key, $value);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // If value is not NULL. retieve key and format HTML
        if ( ! is_null($value = Notices::_get($key)))
        {
            return "$value";
        }
        // If the key does not exist return empty string
        else
        {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

and the setter looks like this:

```
private static function _set($key, $value)
{
    Session::instance()->set($key, $value);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If session settings are playing up on you, check two things:

1. Your [browser cache is not so aggressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771088/controller-in-kohana-3-does-not-appear-to-work-but-has-in-the-background) that it appears to hold on to remnants of elements unless you force flush it.
2. You're not also setting the session in the same method, thus having it re-fill the variable when you refresh the page or call the method again.

You should also check out the existing `get_once` method in the **Kohana_Session** class that destroys the variable after it's done taking it out of the `$_SESSION` variable:

```
/**
 * Get and delete a variable from the session array.
 *
 *     $bar = $session->get_once('bar');
 *
 * @param   string  variable name
 * @param   mixed   default value to return
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function get_once($key, $default = NULL)
{
    $value = $this->get($key, $default);

    unset($this->_data[$key]);

    return $value;
}
```